# console.log of array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am trying to take two pieces of data from an object and push it as a new object into an array. The data is being supplied by an API call to my SQL database. That API call is working correctly and displaying the object in a console table. When the script runs a forEach method to extract the data into its own object and then push that new object to a new array, the new array returns "undefined". Code below:

*Example data (only one placeholder entry currently, the events array will be seeded with multiple examples in this format)*

```
events = [{location: "Emergency Shelter", latitude: "37.5434", longitude: "-77.4435"}]
```

*Empty arrays declared and API call functioning properly:*

```
let events = [];
let locations = [];

$.get("/api/events", data => {
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   events.push(data[i]);
 }
});
```

console.table displays the object correctly and includes the keys "latitude" and "longitude" with the correct corresponding values

*forEach method:*

```
locations = events.forEach(location => {
  const coords = {};
  coords.latitude = location.latitude;
  coords.longitude = location.longitude;
  locations.push(coords);
});
console.log("Coordinates list: " + locations);
```

console.log displays "Coordinates list: undefined"

I feel like I may be missing a return somewhere, but I'm not sure where. I tried adding

```
return locations;
```

inside the forEach method but it doesn't change anything (and I believe that would exit my function prior to getting through the entire array). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `events` is not an array, but an object. Are you sure about that?

Comment: It is an array of objects. Was missing brackets around my example data. Just edited.

Comment: This is quite straight forward. Please try to run my updated answer.

Comment: Part of the issue was a scope problem inside the API call. Events was an empty array outside of the API function. I have corrected that and now console.log(events) displays the objects correctly outside of the API function. I have tried both the map approach and the foreach approach @baymax and Peter Seliger have provided and still the console.log(locations) just displays an empty array. Thank you both for the continued help on this.

Comment: It is now working using the map method. It seems odd to me, but the solution was to run the map method after also pushing the values inside of the API call as shown below. If I remove one or the other, the array is empty. Seems redundant, but it works. 
    $.get("/api/events", data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        events.push(data[i]);
        locations.push({
          id: data[i].id,
          latitude: data[i].latitude,
          longitude: data[i].longitude
        });
      }
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` returns nothing so `locations` should be `undefined`. You shouldn't pass return value of `forEach` to `locations`

```js
events.forEach(location => {
  const coords = {};
  coords.latitude = location.latitude;
  coords.longitude = location.longitude;
  locations.push(coords);
});
console.log("Coordinates list: " + locations);
```

Also you can use `map` function.

```js
const events = [
  { location: 'Emergency Shelter', latitude: '37.5434', longitude: '-77.4435' }
];
const locations = events.map(({ latitude, longitude }) => ({
  latitude,
  longitude
}));

console.log(locations);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how would I get the coords object into the locations array when I need the location function to loop through the existing array called events and grab each set of coordinates?

Comment: I think my answer should work. After `forEach` function you will get `locations` array with coordinates.

Comment: Aha, Thanks again. I see, the forEach should just be run as a method on events and not defining the locations array. I made the adjustment and now it displays "Coordinates list: [object Object].

Comment: You will see [object Object] for array when it is logged. If you want to see the full log you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(locations))`

Comment: *"Thanks for the reply. So how would I get the coords object into the locations array when I need the location function to loop through the existing array called events and grab each set of coordinates?"* ... Try a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based approach which also would condense your code to ... `const locations = events.map(({ latitude, longitude }) => ({ latitude, longitude }));`

Comment: I am not sure what you're wondering. Current code will give the result to `locations` as you wish. @PeterSeliger's code should work as well.

Comment: can you give me some example data for `events` array?

Answer (score 1):

Try a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) based approach which also would condense your code to ...

```js
const events = [{
  location: "Emergency Shelter",
  latitude: "37.5434",
  longitude: "-77.4435"
}, {
  location: "Peopl's Kitchen",
  latitude: "36",
  longitude: "-78"
}, {
  location: "Salvation Army",
  latitude: "38",
  longitude: "-76"
}]; 

const locations = events.map(({ latitude, longitude }) => ({ latitude, longitude }));

console.log("Coordinates list: ", locations); // do not concatenate the result.
console.log("Coordinates list: " + locations);
console.log("Coordinates list: " + JSON.stringify(locations));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

`map` creates a new array by iterating another one where each item of the new array equals the return value of the mapping/transforming function which, at each iteration step, does process the current value of the original array.

Comment: Thanks Peter. So that changed it a little bit. The console log is now showing "Coordinates list: " (basically, not displaying undefined but also not capturing the coords data pushed into locations

Comment: maybe you provide boiled down test data for your `events` array (a list of 3 `event`/`location ` items will do it) ... than one was capable of verifying/demonstrating the provided different approaches.

Comment: Sure thing: added to original post

Comment: the logging of `[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]` is due to your code that concatenates the `locations` result ... `console.log("Coordinates list: " + locations)` whereas it needs to be `console.log("Coordinates list: ", locations)` in order to log some readable data structure(s).